# Printing letter frequency of a string

Tags: c, string, frequency, getchar, letter

Just wondering why this doesnt work. I want to read an input using getchar() and print the character, the percentage/100 and then the frequency. e.g. hallo will print for a:
'a' 0.200000 1
and so on for every character to z.
It accepts input but doesnt print anything:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    double array[26] = {0};
    int i=0;
    double count=0;
    int j =0;
    int start = 'a';
    int point = 0;
    while (i != EOF) {
            i=getchar();
            if(i>='a' && i<='z' && i!=-1) {
                point= i-'a';
                array[point] = array[point] +1;
                count= count+1;
            }
            else if(i>='A' && i<='Z' && i!=-1) {
                point = i - 'A';
                array[point] = array[point] +1;
                count= count+1;
            }
    }
    while (j<=25) {
        printf("'%c' %.6f %.0f", start, (count/array[j]), array[j]);
        j++;
        start++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: `i!=-1` not needed in `if(i>='A' && i<='Z' && i!=-1)`.  `A-Z` cannot have negative value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you calculate the percentage is wrong.

`printf("'%c' %.6f %.0f", start, (count/array[j]), array[j]);`

should be

`printf("'%c' %.6f%% %.0f\n", start, (array[j]/count*100), array[j]);`

Comment: Yes thats a good fix, however, it isnt printing anything, and stops at i=getchar(). for some reason i always equals 10 when it stops.

Comment: What equals 10? @maxphat

Comment: Execution stops when i=10 on line 10, where i=getchar()

Comment: @maxphat If you input data from terminal, press `enter` and input `ctrl + z` when you want to stop input on Windows, or press `enter` and input `ctrl + d` when you want to stop input on Linux.

Comment: When i click crtl + c, it shows that. Do i need to click ctrl + d after ive inputted?

Comment: @maxphat because you wrote `while (i != EOF)` and you need to input `EOF` to tell the program that you want to stop.

Comment: @maxphat I think you shouldn't click ctrl + c, check [here](https://superuser.com/questions/169051/whats-the-difference-between-c-and-d-for-unix-mac-os-x-terminal) to see the
 difference between ^c and ^d